# How to remove case insensitive redundancies in Python lists?

Tags: python

How to remove redundancy in this list:
['#ffffff','#FFFFFF']
I know this is not redundancy but still their value is same as I am dealing with CSS files.
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: hello, whathaveyoutried.com ? Could you please post your attempt(s) before asking the community?

Comment: list(set(a)) considering a as the list containing redundant item.

Comment: I want to know whether there is any method to do this in python as I am new to this. I am too lazy to take C language approach to solve this ;)

Comment: Laziness is never an excuse my friend

Comment: well Python has made me lazy..can't help it ;)

Comment: Good question - just what the compact technique I was looking for. Thanks for asking it ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll probably want this:

```
l = list(set(i.lower() for i in l))
```

Comment: Excellent - very elegant technique.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
l = ['#ffffff', '#FFFFFF', '#123456']
l = [i.lower() for i in l]
l = set(l)
```

or

```
l = ['#ffffff', '#FFFFFF', '#123456']
l = set(i.lower() for i in l)
```

EDIT: Renamed the list upon the suggestion of Snakes and Coffee

Comment: Don't use `list`.  That's a builtin function

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> colors = ['#ffffff','#FFFFFF']
>>> list(set(map(str.lower, colors)))
['#ffffff']
```

See [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

or

```
>>> list(set(color.lower() for color in colors))
['#ffffff']
```

Comment: Instead of `import string`, you could use `str.lower` instead.